# Handling outliers in estimated forward rates

Tags: statistics, regression, estimation

I am estimating forward interest rates. Historically i observe that the daily change in interest rate is less than 0.05% at 90 percentile.

If my estimated rate for a given day is 8.50% and previous day is 8.00% can i revise the estimated rate to 8.05% considering the maximum daily change is 0.05%?

Any thoughts please?

Comment: This is not at all clear.  Obviously, old estimates of future values have to get updated as new information arises.  Is that all you are asking?

Comment: It might indicate that your model is bad; i.e. it might have overfit and is throwing out very unreasonable answers. However, if you truly think that the max daily change is 0.05%, and your model is spitting out 0.5%, *and* you still believe that your model is accurate, then obviously you should trade on this information.

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is unclear what you are asking.  If you can, please edit your post to provide more detail.  What model are you using to make the estimate?  As a general note, if you find yourself in the habit of overruling your own model because the results it gives feel badly wrong to you, that's a sure sign that you need a better model.

Comment: In a situation like this when you’re making predictions of the next day with information on what happened the previous day, you should generally 1) have the previous day value (and longer lags) in your model. 2) Have compared your model’s performance to simply using yesterday’s value to predict today. (And simple smoothing methods.) If your model makes an extreme prediction, you should focus on understanding why. So you can either find how to improve the model or become comfortable with “believing” the prediction.